# Which of the Elliptic Curves are supported for the Rancher Kubernetes certificates?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, elliptic-curve, rancher-rke

## Problem

I have generated keys and certificates by OpenSSL with the secp256k1, run `rke` version v1.2.8 from the Rancher Kubernetes Engine (RKE), and got the following error:

```
FATA[0000] Failed to read certificates from dir [/home/max/cluster_certs]: failed to read certificate [kube-apiserver-requestheader-ca.pem]: x509: unsupported elliptic curve
```

`kubectl version`:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.1", GitCommit:"5e58841cce77d4bc13713ad2b91fa0d961e69192", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-05-12T14:18:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I have generated the root CA key and certificate the following way:

```
openssl ecparam -name secp256k1 -genkey -noout -out ca-pvt.pem -rand random.bin -writerand random.bin
openssl req -config .\openssl.cnf -x509 -sha256 -new -nodes -key ca-pvt.pem -days 10227 -out ca-cert.cer -rand random.bin -writerand random.bin
```

Then I used it to sign the CSRs generated by `rke cert generate-csr` from my Kubernetes Rancher `cluster.yml`.

The command line to approve a CSR was the following:

```
openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -batch -in %1 -out %2 -create_serial -notext -rand random.bin -writerand random.bin
```

## Question

Which curves are supported today by Kubernetes for the certificates if `secp256k1` yields the `x509: unsupported elliptic curve` error message?

## P.S.

I have also tried the `prime256v1`, also known as `secp256r1`. It progressed further comparing to `secp256k1`, but still got an error.

With  `prime256v1`, RKE did not complain `x509: unsupported elliptic curve`.

Instead, it gave an error `panic: interface conversion: interface {} is *ecdsa.PrivateKey, not *rsa.PrivateKey`. Here is the full error message:

Here is the full error message:

```
DEBU[0000] Certificate file [./cluster_certs/kube-apiserver-requestheader-ca.pem] content is greater than 0 
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is *ecdsa.PrivateKey, not *rsa.PrivateKey 
goroutine 1 [running]: github.com/rancher/rke/pki.getKeyFromFile(0x7ffe6294c74e, 0xf, 0xc00105cb10, 0x27, 0x8, 0xc00105cb10, 0x27) 
/go/src/github.com/rancher/rke/pki/util.go:656 +0x212
```

Comment: Hi @MaximMasiutin, did you try to change your curve to `secp256r1`? The main difference is that `secp256k1` is a Koblitz curve, while `secp256r1` is not. Koblitz curves are known to be a few bits weaker than other curves.

Comment: You can also try with curve `prime256v1`

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak - You are right, if I specify "secp256r1", OpenSSL gives the following message: `using curve name prime256v1 instead of secp256r1`. OpenSSL supports "secp256r1", it is just called "prime256v1". Check section 2.1.1.1 in RFC 5480, where the "secp192r1" curve is called "prime192v1" and the "secp256r1" curve is called "prime256v1".

Comment: is your problem now resolved?

Comment: I have already installed a cluster with RSA, so I now need to set up a test environment to test the EC curves (ECDSA) instead of RSA, for faster operation. I will let you know as soon as I do that.

Comment: Do you have any progress?

Comment: RKE did not work with prime256v1 (AKA secp256r1) also. It progressed further comparing to secp256k1, but still got an error.

Comment: I've tried to make a CA key file (kube-service-account-token-key.pem and kube-apiserver-requestheader-ca-key.pem - both having the same contents) with ECDSA and got the following error:

Comment: DEBU[0000] Certificate file [./cluster_certs/kube-apiserver-requestheader-ca.pem] content is greater than 0 panic: interface conversion: interface {} is *ecdsa.PrivateKey, not *rsa.PrivateKey goroutine 1 [running]: github.com/rancher/rke/pki.getKeyFromFile(0x7ffe6294c74e, 0xf, 0xc00105cb10, 0x27, 0x8, 0xc00105cb10, 0x27) /go/src/github.com/rancher/rke/pki/util.go:656 +0x212

Comment: However, when I generate the CA key (kube-service-account-token-key.pem and kube-apiserver-requestheader-ca-key.pem) with RSA, so everything is the same except the algorithm - it works.

Comment: I have put the scripts that I have used to generate the keys to https://github.com/maximmasiutin/openssl-ca-automation

Answer (score 12):

> Which curves are supported today by Kubernetes for the certificates if `secp256k1` yields the `x509: unsupported elliptic curve` error message?

To try to answer this question I will look directly at the [source code](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/8bf6e09f4cbb0242039dd4602f1f2d58e30e0f26/src/crypto/x509/x509.go). You can find there lines, that gives an error `unsupported elliptic curve`:

```
case *ecdsa.PublicKey:
        publicKeyBytes = elliptic.Marshal(pub.Curve, pub.X, pub.Y)
        oid, ok := oidFromNamedCurve(pub.Curve)
        if !ok {
            return nil, pkix.AlgorithmIdentifier{}, errors.New("x509: unsupported elliptic curve")
        }
```

There are two functions here that are responsible for processing the curve:

- Marshal:

```
// Marshal converts a point on the curve into the uncompressed form specified in
// section 4.3.6 of ANSI X9.62.
func Marshal(curve Curve, x, y *big.Int) []byte {
    byteLen := (curve.Params().BitSize + 7) / 8

    ret := make([]byte, 1+2*byteLen)
    ret[0] = 4 // uncompressed point

    x.FillBytes(ret[1 : 1+byteLen])
    y.FillBytes(ret[1+byteLen : 1+2*byteLen])

    return ret
}
```

- oidFromNamedCurve:

```
// OIDFromNamedCurve returns the OID used to specify the use of the given
// elliptic curve.
func OIDFromNamedCurve(curve elliptic.Curve) (asn1.ObjectIdentifier, bool) {
    switch curve {
    case elliptic.P224():
        return OIDNamedCurveP224, true
    case elliptic.P256():
        return OIDNamedCurveP256, true
    case elliptic.P384():
        return OIDNamedCurveP384, true
    case elliptic.P521():
        return OIDNamedCurveP521, true
    case secp192r1():
        return OIDNamedCurveP192, true
    }

    return nil, false
}
```

The final answer is therefore in the switch. Supported elliptic curves are:

- [elliptic.P224](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/elliptic/#P224)
- [elliptic.P256](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/elliptic/#P521)
- [elliptic.P384](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/elliptic/#P384)
- [elliptic.P521](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/elliptic/#P521)
- secp192r1

You need to  change your curve to `secp256r1`. The main difference is that `secp256k1` is a Koblitz curve, while `secp256r1` is not. Koblitz curves are known to be a few bits weaker than other curves.

> OpenSSL supports "secp256r1", it is just called "prime256v1". Check section 2.1.1.1 in RFC 5480, where the "secp192r1" curve is called "prime192v1" and the "secp256r1" curve is called "prime256v1".

Comment: It seems that ECDSA keys are not supported anyway. I've tried to make a CA key file (kube-service-account-token-key.pem and kube-apiserver-requestheader-ca-key.pem - both having the same contents) with ECDSA and got the following error:

Comment: DEBU[0000] Certificate file [./cluster_certs/kube-apiserver-requestheader-ca.pem] content is greater than 0

panic: interface conversion: interface {} is *ecdsa.PrivateKey, not *rsa.PrivateKey

goroutine 1 [running]:

github.com/rancher/rke/pki.getKeyFromFile(0x7ffe6294c74e, 0xf, 0xc00105cb10, 0x27, 0x8, 0xc00105cb10, 0x27)

        /go/src/github.com/rancher/rke/pki/util.go:656 +0x212

Comment: However, when I generate the CA key (kube-service-account-token-key.pem and kube-apiserver-requestheader-ca-key.pem) with RSA, so everything is the same except the algorithm - it works.

Comment: I have given you a link to the source code. In the same function on which I based my answer you will find the [line](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/8bf6e09f4cbb0242039dd4602f1f2d58e30e0f26/src/crypto/x509/x509.go#78):  `return nil, pkix.AlgorithmIdentifier{}, errors.New("x509: only RSA and ECDSA public keys supported")`. Based on this ECDSA keys are supported.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! I have put the scripts that I have used to generate the keys to https://github.com/maximmasiutin/openssl-ca-automation